# How to subscribe Lambda to an AWS Iot Jobs topic in Serverless Framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-iot

I'm using the Serverless Framework and I need to subscribe my Lambda function to an AWS Iot Jobs topic, more specifically the "start-next/#" topic. I already have another Lambda function subscribed to another topic of the AWS Iot tools, using this piece of code in the serverless.yml file:

```
    events:
      - iot:
          sql: "SELECT topic() AS topic, * FROM '$aws/things/+/shadow/update'"
```

This works just fine, the Lambda function is triggered and I'm able to process what I need, but when I try to use this piece of code:

```
    events:
      - iot:
          sql: "SELECT topic() AS topic, * FROM '$aws/things/+/jobs/start-next/#'"
```

it simply will not work no matter what I try to do.
Could someone give me any sugestions of what I can do to trigger my Lambda function when new messages are published to the '$aws/things/+/jobs/start-next' topic?

Comment: I have dealt with serverless framework, but never with AWS IOT, but i found this article which may be helpful: https://serverless.zone/iot-with-the-serverless-framework-e228fae87be, It includes gists (and the gists have links to other .yml files).

Answer (score 0):

Using the wildcard **#** at the end of the query you make your rule subscribes to any topic beginning with

```
'$aws/things/thingName/jobs/start-next/[...]'
'$aws/things/thingName/jobs/start-next/[...]/[...]'
'...'
```

If you are publishing a message to a topic like this by any chance (with nothing after **/start-next**)

```
$aws/things/thingName/jobs/start-next
```

Then it won't match your rule. In such scenario, you should query without the '#' wildcard at the end. Something like this

```
'sql: "SELECT topic() AS topic, * FROM '$aws/things/+/jobs/start-next'"'
```

You can find more details about such wildcards and its coverage [right here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sql-from.html)

Comment: According to the AWS IOT documentation right here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/jobs-api.html#mqtt-(13), in order to receive the details of a job, you need to subscribe to the '$aws/things/{thingName}/jobs/start-next/#' topic, or the '/accepted' topic for successfull requests, or the '/rejected' topic for failed requests, but in my case I want to receive messages in both cases. I'll try your sugestion but I doubt it'll work given the documentation instructions

Comment: In this case you're right. The **#** would match to **../rejected** or  **../accepted**.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately it still doesn't work :/ Also I realized I've already tried your suggestion, but no good on that either, appreciate the will to help anyways :) I'll try configuring the .yml file with some of the things shown in the link suggested by @Mu-Majid to see if it works

Comment: What a shame. I'd suggest you creating a rule manually through painel to send messages to a SNS. Then you can subscribe your email so that you can speed tests up. Let us know if u get any success

Comment: We (my team) actually thought about this, but the thing is that the rule appears to simply not be executed. The Lambda doesn't get triggered, so I'm not sure if changing the action for the rule from invoking the Lambda to publishing a message on a SNS topic would work. But I'll try

Comment: Yeah, no luck with that either :/ not receiving any emails after some publishes to the ../start-next topic. I'm really out of ideas for this one

Comment: Now it's time to make sure that your thing is actually publishing into the correct topic. First set up https://mqttfx.jensd.de/ and publish to the topic manually. Then, see if it gets triggered. If so, that means your thing is publishing somewhere else.

Comment: I've made a subscription to the ../start-next/accepted topic on the application from which I publish to the ../start-next topic, to simulate a real workflow following the AWS IOT docs. I assure you that my thing is publishing to the correct topic, because in this application I receive the jobs details on the ../start-next/accepted topic and if I subscribe to it on the MQTT Client I also get the jobs details :/ even so, my Lambda doesn't get triggered

Answer (score 0):

So... Reading the MQTT Client Help on the IOT page, I've actually found this part:

```
Reserved topics

Topics beginning with $ are considered reserved and are not supported for publishing and 
subscribing except when working with the Thing Shadows service. To learn more, 
see Thing Shadows.
```

which would explain why the shadows topic triggers the Lambda as I mentioned in the question, but not my other Lambda based on the jobs topics.
I guess I'll have to find another way to make this work, but thanks to who tried to help :)